# Expressão regular para Java (validando senha)

Tags: java, regex

Preciso de uma expressão regular para validar a seguinte senha:

A senha deve conter **pelo menos um elemento de cada**:

1. Mais do que 6 caracteres;
2. Letras maiúsculas e minúsculas;
3. Números;
4. Caracteres especiais.

Atualmente, eu tenho isso:

```
if(senha.matches("(^|$)[a-z]+(^|$)[0-9]")) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, senha.matches("(^|$)[a-z]+(^|$)[0-9]"));
}

else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, senha.matches("(^|$)[a-z]+(^|$)[0-9]"));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem que ser expressão regular? Pergunto isso porque determinar que usar expressão regular é necessário me parece ser um caso de [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/132).

Se o uso de expressões regulares não for obrigatório, você pode fazer isso:

```
public static boolean senhaForte(String senha) {
    if (senha.length() < 6) return false;

    boolean achouNumero = false;
    boolean achouMaiuscula = false;
    boolean achouMinuscula = false;
    boolean achouSimbolo = false;
    for (char c : senha.toCharArray()) {
         if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
             achouNumero = true;
         } else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
             achouMaiuscula = true;
         } else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
             achouMinuscula = true;
         } else {
             achouSimbolo = true;
         }
    }
    return achouNumero && achouMaiuscula && achouMinuscula && achouSimbolo;
}
```

E isso ainda tem a vantagem de que se você precisar alterar o critério do que é considerado uma senha forte, é bem mais fácil de se mexer nisso do que em uma expressão regular.

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, foi de muita valia sua ajuda, o código rodou lindo :D
Realmente, desta forma eu não preciso usar expressões regulares para validar, muito mais fácil o entendimento.